# Disable wrapping in Xtext formatter

Tags: xtext

I have a xtext grammar which consists of one declaration per line. When I format the code, all the declarations end up in the same line, the line breaks are removed.

As I didn't manage to change the grammar to require line breaks, I would like to disable the removal of line breaks. How do I do that? Bonus points if someone can tell me how to require line breaks at the end of each declaration.

Part of the Grammar:

```
grammar com.example.Msg with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
hidden(WS, SL_COMMENT) 

import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore

generate msg_idl "http://www.example.com/ex/ample/msg"

Model:
    MsgDef
;


MsgDef:
     (definitions+=definition)+ 
;

definition:
    type=fieldType ' '+ name=ValidID (' '* '=' ' '* const=Value)?
;


fieldType:
    value = ( builtinType |  header)    
;



builtinType:
    BOOL    = "bool" 
  | INT32   = "int32"
  | CHAR    = "char"
;

header:
    value="Header"
;

Bool_l:
    target=BOOL_E
;


String_l:
    target =  ('""'|STRING)
;

Number_l:
    Double_l | Integer_l | NegInteger_l
;


NegInteger_l:
    target=NEG_INT
;

Integer_l :
    target=INT
;

Double_l:
    target=DOUBLE
;

terminal NEG_INT returns ecore::EInt:
  '-' INT 
;

terminal DOUBLE returns ecore::EDouble :
  ('-')? ('0'..'9')* ('.' INT) |
  ('-')? INT ('.') | 
  ('-')? INT ('.' ('0'..'9')*)? (('e'|'E')('-'|'+')? INT )| 
  'nan' | 'inf' | '-inf'
;

enum BOOL_E :
    true | false 
;

ValidID: 
    "bool" 
  | "string"
  | "time"
  | "duration"
  | "char"
  | ID ;


Value:
    String_l | Number_l
;

  terminal SL_COMMENT :
    ' '* '#' !('\n'|'\r')* ('\r'? '\n')? 
;
```

Example data

```
string left
string top
string right
string bottom
```

I already tried:

```
class MsgFormatter extends AbstractDeclarativeFormatter {

    extension MsgGrammarAccess msgGrammarAccess = grammarAccess as MsgGrammarAccess

    override protected void configureFormatting(FormattingConfig c) {
        c.setLinewrap(0, 1, 2).before(SL_COMMENTRule)
        c.setLinewrap(0, 1, 2).before(ML_COMMENTRule)
        c.setLinewrap(0, 1, 1).after(ML_COMMENTRule)

        c.setLinewrap().before(definitionRule); // does not work
        c.setLinewrap(1,1,2).before(definitionRule); // does not work
        c.setLinewrap().before(fieldTypeRule); // does not work

    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that calling the formatter once makes the syntax invalid. Then calling it again will collapse the lines. I am using Xtext 2.8.4

Answer (score 0):

In general it is a bad idea to encode whitespace into the language itself. Most of the time it is better to write the language in a way that you can use all kinds of whitespaces (blanks, tabs, newlines ...) to separate tokens.

You should implement a custom formatter for your language that inserts the line breaks after each statement. Xtext comes with two formatter APIs (an old one and a new one starting with Xtext 2.8). I propose to use the new one.

Here you extend `AbstractFormatter2` and implement the `format` methods.

You can find a bit information in the online manual: https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/303_runtime_concepts.html#formatting

Some more explanation in the folowing blog post: https://blogs.itemis.com/en/tabular-formatting-with-the-new-formatter-api

Some technical background: https://de.slideshare.net/meysholdt/xtexts-new-formatter-api